# Select all Vertices with outE filters connecting to a specific list of Vertices

Tags: orientdb

I'm new to ODB, but not SQL, and can't seem to find a tutorial to learn from, or a even similar q&a; but that's likely my inability to ask the question correctly.

I'm looking for a way to find all Vertices of a particular class (e.g. Claim) which have at least one specific outE class (e.g. available_to_role) and those Edges all have a particular property value (e.g. role="adj1") and those Edges also all have on their corresponding other edge a particular Vertices with a particular property value (e.g. date).

I've tried searching from both sides of the edge and from the edge in particular but it doesn't work as expected.  I always get all Claims vertices connected with any one date of a list of more than one date, and not only the Claims that match with all dates.

This is the closest I've gotten, but it results in Claims returned that are only available on one of the two dates, I'm not sure how to force an && result to only get claims available on all dates provided.

```
SELECT
    *,
    out.label as claim_label,
    in.date as date,
    count(in.date)
FROM
    available_to_role
WHERE
    role='adj1'
AND
    in.date in ['2018-06-02 00:00:00','2018-06-03 00:00:00']
GROUP BY
    in.date
```

I'm looking for a way to get all Claims that are available to a particular role on all the dates supplied, not just one of the dates supplied.  And, I need those results as individual responses, not aggregated (e.g. ["role","role"] ["date","date"]).  In all case, I know the dates and roles, but not the Claims.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have undertood correctly but:

try this:

```
select from Claims where outE("available_to_role").role contains "adj1" and out("available_to_role").date in ['2018-06-02 00:00:00','2018-06-03 00:00:00']
```

if you want to make sure that the vertex in Claims class match both dates you have to use AND condition for both dates

Hope it helps

Regards